# Normalization of Time Series for GARCH

Tags: time-series, normalization, normality-assumption, garch

It is generally observed that financial times series is not normally distributed. So I want to clear the following doubts:

1. Is it necessary to normalize time series data especially before proceeding with models such as GARCH?
2. If the time series is stationary is it still necessary to normalize it?
3. How to normalize it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. In statistics, *to normalize X* does not mean *to make X normally distributed*. Rather, there are [several other possible meanings](https://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/normalization/info). It is not necessary to do any of those things before GARCH modelling.
2. Regardless of stationarity, you do not have to normalize your time series.
3. Since the term *to normalize* has several possible meanings, which one (if any) are you interested in?